# change order of integration in a double integral

Tags: integration

can someone please help me what is the reverse of these double integrals ?

$\int _0^a\:\int _0^{a-x}\:\left(1\right)dy\:dx$

$\int _0^a\:\int _0^x\:\left(x+y\right)dy\:dx$

$\int _0^2\:\int _0^{1-\left(y-1\right)^2}\:\left(x\right)dx\:dy$

$\int _{-\frac{\pi }{2}}^{\frac{\pi }{2}}\:\int _0^{2a\:cos\theta }\:\left(r\right)dr\:d\theta $

I solved the second one but not sure

$ \int _0^a\int _y^a\:\:\left(x+y\right)\:dx\:dy $

Comment: Graphing the problems might help..

Comment: I tried graphing but didn't know how to do the last two

Comment: got the first two but stuck with the third and fourth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Try rewriting the integral boundaries using indicator functions. For the third one:

$$ \int_{0}^{2} \int_{0}^{1-(y-1)^2} x \;dx \;dy = \int_{0}^{2} \int_{0}^{1} \chi_{[0, 1-(y-1)^2]}(x) \cdot  x \;dx \;dy$$

Now for $x \in [0,1]$, we can rewrite the integral boundaries:

$$ 0 \leq x \leq 1 - (y-1)^2 \quad \Leftrightarrow \quad 1 - \sqrt{1-x} \leq y \leq 1 + \sqrt{1-x} $$

Now we can rewrite the integral:

$$\int_{0}^{2} \int_{0}^{1} \chi_{[0, 1-(y-1)^2]}(x) \cdot  x \;dx \;dy = \int_{0}^{2} \int_{0}^{1} \chi_{[1-\sqrt{1-x}, 1+ \sqrt{1-x}]}(y) \cdot  x \;dx \;dy =$$
$$ =\int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{2} \chi_{[1-\sqrt{1-x}, 1+ \sqrt{1-x}]}(y) \cdot  x \;dy \;dx  = \int_{0}^{1} \int_{1-\sqrt{1-x}}^{1+\sqrt{1-x}}  x \;dy \;dx $$

Try doing the last one in this way.

EDIT: Because the OP had trouble with the last one I'll do it too:

$$ \int_{-\pi /2 }^{\pi/ 2} \int_{0}^{2a \cos(\theta)} r \;dr \;d\theta = \int_{-\pi /2 }^{\pi/ 2} \int_{0}^{2a } \chi_{[0, 2a \cos(\theta)]}(r) \cdot r \;dr \;d\theta$$ Again, we're going to rewrite the integral boundaries: For $r \in [0, 2a]$ we have

$$ 0 \leq r \leq 2a \cos(\theta) \Leftrightarrow -\frac{\pi}{2} \leq \theta \leq -\arccos(\frac{r}{2a}) \quad \mathrm{or} \quad \arccos(\frac{r}{2a}) \leq \theta \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$$

For ease of notation, let $A := [-\frac{\pi}{2}, -\arccos(\frac{r}{2a})] \cup [\arccos(\frac{r}{2a}), \frac{\pi}{2}]$. This way we can write the above integral as follows

$$ \int_{-\pi /2 }^{\pi/ 2} \int_{0}^{2a } \chi_{A}(\theta) \cdot r \;dr \;d\theta = \int_{0}^{2a} \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \chi_{A}(\theta) \cdot r \;d\theta\;dr$$

Now because the integrand is symmetric in $\theta$, meaning $\chi_{A}(\theta) = \chi_{A}(-\theta)$,  we can write this as

$$2 \int_{0}^{2a} \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \chi_{A}(\theta) \cdot r \;d\theta\;dr = 2 \int_{0}^{2a} \int_{\arccos(r/2a)}^{\pi/2} r \;d\theta\;dr$$

Comment: Thank you very much,, I tried the last one many times but I get wrong answer every time I check it I got different answer than the original one

Comment: @ASD123 I added an answer to the fourth problem.